# Cisco 881w AP password recovery

Tags: cisco, access-point, password-recovery

Hello I lost the passwords for my Cisco 881w and internal Access Point. I used the procedure [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/800-series-routers/12065-pswdrec-827.html) to reset the password on the router by booting into `rommon` and changing `confreg` to `0x2142`. This allowed me to boot into the router without dumping the saved config. Now I can telnet/SSH into the router just fine, but still do not have access to the AP.

I know that I can reset the AP but this one has a rather complex config and I would rather not just reset it.

How do I reset the AP password without overwriting the existing config?

Comment: Have you contacted cisco directly?

Comment: @mdpc, no I haven't. They won't talk to me anyway without a service contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no way to do a password recovery on embedded AP, only a password reset. this is achieved by resetting AP back to factory default which I laid out above. I know this isn't the answer they were looking for but this is per Cisco wireless TAC.

Answer (score 0):

Try cisco/cisco or Cisco/Cisco first. If that doesn't work reset to defualt config and start over like this:

VHSLAS1-TST-1#service-module wlan-ap 0 reset default-config
VHSLASTEST-1#service-module wlan-ap 0 session
Trying 192.168.104.1, 2002 ... Open

#

File "flash:/ap801-k9w7-mx.124-25d.JA1/ap801-k9w7-mx.124-25d.JA1" uncompressed and installed, entry point: 0x3000
executing...

```
          Restricted Rights Legend
```

Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is
subject to restrictions as set forth in subparagraph
(c) of the Commercial Computer Software - Restricted
Rights clause at FAR sec. 52.227-19 and subparagraph
(c) (1) (ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer
Software clause at DFARS sec. 252.227-7013.

```
       cisco Systems, Inc.
       170 West Tasman Drive
       San Jose, California 95134-1706
```

Cisco IOS Software, AP801 Software (AP801-K9W7-M), Version 12.4(25d)JA1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2011 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Thu 11-Aug-11 02:29 by prod_rel_team

Proceeding with system init

Proceeding to unmask interrupts
Initializing flashfs...
FLASH CHIP:  Spansion Mirrorbit (0001)

flashfs[1]: 150 files, 7 directories
flashfs[1]: 0 orphaned files, 0 orphaned directories
flashfs[1]: Total bytes: 31223808
flashfs[1]: Bytes used: 6587904
flashfs[1]: Bytes available: 24635904
flashfs[1]: flashfs fsck took 5 seconds.
flashfs[1]: Initialization complete....done Initializing flashfs.

Warning:  the compile-time code checksum does not appear to be present.

Radio0  present 8363 8000 A8020000 0 A8030000 30
Radio1 not present 0 0 0 0 0 11
This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:
http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.

cisco AP801GN-A-K9         (PowerPC 8343) processor (revision B0) with 49142K/16384K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FTX171384FU
PowerPC 8343 CPU at 400Mhz, revision number 0x0031
Last reset from power-on
1 Gigabit Ethernet interface
1 802.11 Radio(s)

32K bytes of flash-simulated non-volatile configuration memory.
Base ethernet MAC Address: 2C:54:2D:B9:C2:B4
Part Number                          : 73-11027-11
PCA Assembly Number                  : 800-28807-11
PCA Revision Number                  : B0
PCB Serial Number                    : FOC16523EC2
Top Assembly Part Number             : 800-29553-06
Top Assembly Serial Number           : FTX171384FU
Top Revision Number                  : E0
Product/Model Number                 : AP801GN-A-K9

### % Password change notice.

Default username/password setup on AP is cisco/cisco with privilege level 15.
It is strongly suggested that you create a new username with privilege level 
15 using the following command for console security.

username  privilege 15 secret 0 
no username cisco

Replace  and  with the username and password you want to 
use. After you change your username/password you can turn off this message 
by configuring  "no banner login" and "no banner exec" in privileged mode.

---

User Access Verification

Username: cisco
Password:

### % Password change notice.

Default username/password setup on AP is cisco/cisco with privilege level 15. 
It is strongly suggested that you create a new username with privilege level 
15 using the following command for console security.

username  privilege 15 secret 0 
no username cisco

Replace  and  with the username and password you want to 
use. After you change your username/password you can turn off this message 
by configuring  "no banner login" and "no banner exec" in privileged mode.

---

ap#

Press RETURN to get started!

Comment: Thanks, but 98% of this answer don't seem to apply to the question at all. The 2% that do seem unhelpful, as the OP has explicitly stated that a reset, while possible, is not desirable to them.

Comment: Actually there is no way to do a password recovery on embedded AP, only a password reset. this is achieved by resetting AP back to factory default which I laid out above. I know this isn't the answer they were looking for but this is per Cisco wireless TAC.